# Read response from JSR223 Assertion to Java Code

Tags: java, jmeter, jmx

I want to read processed value from Java code.  I have a jsr233 assertion in my jmx which processed values ({"timestamp" : 23893865465, "diff" : 34}) I want to read this in my java code after invoking run() command in my JMeterEngine instance.

I tried using SamplerListner but not working. how I can read that response.

JSR 233 Assertion Code :

```
 mport groovy.json.JsonBuilder

String totalIDs = vars.get("assetIdCount_matchNr");
Integer result = Integer.valueOf(totalIDs);
Date currentDate = new Date();
if (result > 10){
    vars.put("SEARCH_SUCCESS_TIMESTAMP",currentDate.getTime().toString());
    log.info("ASSET_CREATION_TIMESTAMP:" + props.get("ASSET_CREATION_TIMESTAMP"));
    log.info("ASSET_CREATION_TIMESTAMPAfter:" + props.get("ASSET_CREATION_TIMESTAMP"));
    log.info("SEARCH_SUCCESS_TIMESTAMP:" + vars.get("SEARCH_SUCCESS_TIMESTAMP"));
    def diff = Long.valueOf(vars.get("SEARCH_SUCCESS_TIMESTAMP").toString()) - Long.valueOf(props.get("ASSET_CREATION_TIMESTAMP").toString());
    def timestamp = vars.get("SEARCH_SUCCESS_TIMESTAMP");
    vars.putObject("Diff", diff);
    log.info(String.valueOf(diff));

    def json = new JsonBuilder()
    def root = json timestamp: "5241234134134", diff: "345"

    def file  = new File(vars.get("file_location").toString())
    file.write('\n'+json.toString());
    sleep 10

    AssertionResult.setFailure(true);
}
```

---

Java code

```
 StandardJMeterEngine jmeterSecondary = configJmeter(jmxFileName, argumentObject, jmeter, jMeterAssetECListnerService); //get the jmeter to run by configuring it

                jmeterSecondary.run();
              // I want to get the timestamp and diff here
                jmeterSecondary.reset();
                jmeterSecondary.exit();
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The easiest option I can think of is using [System.setProperty()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#setProperty(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) function to write the value into a Java System Property in the JSR223 Assertion.

System properties are global for the whole JVM therefore you will be able to access it using [System.getProperty()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getProperty(java.lang.String)) function after you call `jmeterSecondary.run();`

Example usage:

[image]

More information on different JMeter Properties types and ways of working with them: [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization)